# Detect Pixi canvas images loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, pixi.js

I'm working on a PixiJS application where I am dressing up my character. So, different PNG images are loaded to Pixi stage.

There is a button to finish dressing the character and it saves the current canvas using the `.toDataURL()` method.

The problem is that the user can click to change for example the shirt, and while the shirt is changing he can click the finish button, but if the shirt is not fully loaded it saves the canvas without the shirt.

I already make JS callbacks to unlock finish button when my dressing function finishes.

The thing is that javascript code completes successfully and replaces the canvas image, but the image needs a few seconds/miliseconds (depending on internet speed) to load.

During that time if the user clicks the finish button it can result in an incomplete canvas.

How can I detect that the canvas images are fully loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use an image loader and make sure the png image has been loaded, by the browser, before inserting the image to the canvas. So use this: http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.loaders.Loader.html

Comment: Thanks Hachi for Your answer. After creating loader, I tried to add image using loader.load(), and then call loader.once('complete', unlockFinishButton) to unlock my finish button? unlockFinishButton completes before my image is loaded by browser. Probably I didn't understood You well nor the loader. ?

Comment: Sorry for being slow. The loader loads resources using the html image element. So the browser has loaded them, when the loader is finished. At least I don't really see a possible issues there. Could you provide me a small script in plunkr ( https://plnkr.co) or jsfiddle and I could try to check and debug it there? Would be easier, since the loader should fix the issue, unles I've misunderstood the issue, which should tell tha too.

Comment: Yeah, the loader fixed my problem. I load all my images using loader, and then loader.once('complete', callback) -> there in the callback I create my sprites from loader resources and add them to stage.